# how can i add text to my popup label from another class function with kivy

Tags: python, opencv, kivy, popup

I want to display the color name that i found at { closest_colour(requested_colour) } function
in popup window.

In practice application supposed to ask for file from your computer (only specific image types) then ask for mouse input while displaying image that you choose.Finally opens popup window to display color of pixel that you clicked.

.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import cv2
import webcolors

class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

class Root(FloatLayout):
    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load (self,path, filename):
        filename=str(filename)
        filename = filename.replace("[", "")
        filename = filename.replace("]", "")
        filename = filename.replace("\\\\", "\\")
        filename = filename.replace("'", "")
        print(filename)
        img=cv2.imread(filename)
        cv2.imshow('image', img)

        self.dismiss_popup()

        def closest_colour(requested_colour):
            min_colours = {}
            for key, name in webcolors.CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():
                b_c, g_c, r_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
                rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
                gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
                bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2

                min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
            return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]

        def click_event(event, x, y, flags, params):
            if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
                print(x, ' ', y)
                requested_colour=img[y,x]
                global answer
                answer=closest_colour(requested_colour)
                print(closest_colour(requested_colour))
                print(img[y,x])
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        return answer

class MyPopup(Popup):
    PopUp=ObjectProperty(None)
    text = StringProperty(Root.answer)
    def MyPopup(self):
        content = MyPopup(PopUp=self.PopUp)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Color Found!!", content=content, size_hint=(0.2, 0.4))
        self._popup.open()

class main(App):
    pass

Factory.register('Root', cls=Root)
Factory.register('LoadDialog', cls=LoadDialog)
Factory.register('MyPopup', cls=MyPopup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main().run()
```

.kv

```
#:kivy 1.1.0
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

Root:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            id: load
            size_hint:(1,.1)
            pos_hint:{'x':0, 'y':0}
            text: 'Load'
            on_release: root.show_load()
            background_color :(0, 0, 1, 1)
        Image:
            id: img
            size_hint:(1,.9)
            pos_hint:{'x':0, 'y':.1}
            source: 'palet.jpg'
            size: self.texture_size
            keep_ratio: False
            allow_stretch: True

<LoadDialog>:
    id:load_dialog
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserIconView:
            id: filechooser
            filters:['*.png','*.jpg','*.jpeg']
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()
            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
                on_release: Factory.MyPopup().open()

<MyPopup@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint:0.4,0.2
    pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"y":0.4}
    title:"Color Found!!"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:root.text
            font_size:24
        Button:
            text:"Ok"
            width:.5
            size_hint:0.2,0.2
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0}
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

I tried to create global answer variable but it didnt work out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the structure of what you're trying to do is a little confusing, the class LoadDialog(FloatLayout) looks like it's being called just to make the connection between the two classes, is that it?

But from the looks of it, you are trying to pass the text from variable

> answer

that is returned when you call the function def load(). if so, try creating a variable eg text_answer = None in class Root()

then, before returning the result, pass the variable's value to the new variable created within the class, in the code snippet

```
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    # add this
    self.text_answer = answer
    # don't need the return
    return answer
```

later in class MyPopup(Popup), add the variable that was created in the Root() class. But remember that, for object-oriented concepts, you need to use the variable from the instance of class Root() and not directly from the class, and that's the tricky part.

There are many ways to do this:

> Pass the Root() class instance to the Popup constructor.
>
> Use an ObjectProperty to use the Root instance.
>
> Use kivy's own tree of objects, doing self.parent.parent.[...] until
> finding the instance of Root()

For this case, the easiest way is to use the self.parent method, until you find the Root instance and retrieve the text value, try doing something like this:

```
class MyPopup(Popup):
    PopUp=ObjectProperty(None)
    # go looking for the instance of Root in the parentage
    text = StringProperty(self.parent.parent.text_answer)
```

I can't give the answer to your specific problem because I don't have some of the libraries you are using, but I believe this should help with communication between classes.

Always remember to try to reference the instances of the classes, not the classes themselves.

Comment: thank you for answer but still i couldnt figure out how to fix it :(